# Google Maps V3 geocode from XML

Tags: xml, google-maps, geocode

I'm trying to take this example from Google Maps and use an address instead of lat/long to place markers from an XML doc:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/jqueryget.html

Does anyone have any pointers?  Have you used Google Maps to show records using the address and have an example?  I've exhausted all the places I know to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html

I would post more than just a url — but without knowing what the issue is, it's difficult to be specific. If you edit your question to include the bit of your code which is failing (or a link to your page), it should be possible to say exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'd seen that example, but I do not have lat/long to begin with.  This is a sample from my XML file:- <markers>
  <marker address="121 MAINT ST, ABINGDON, VA 24210" /> 
  <marker address="131 MAINT ST, ABINGDON, VA 24210" /> 
  <marker address="141 MAINT ST, ABINGDON, VA 24210" /> 
  <marker address="151 MAINT ST, ABINGDON, VA 24210" /> 
  </markers>

Comment: Taking the above example from that link I would be trying to do this: // Read the data from example.xml
      downloadUrl("example.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var marker = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var address = parseFloat(marker[i].getAttribute("address"));
          var point = new google.maps.address(address);
          // create the marker
          var markers = createMarker(point);
        }

Comment: @user1322600 A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062624/google-map-v3-only-some-markers-are-displayed/10063339#10063339) involved geocoding addresses. In that case the addresses were JSON data (or hard coded), but the same method will work for XML data once the data is available.