# gmaps4jsf version 3.0.0 how to set markers based on address rather than lat/long?

Tags: jsf-2, gmaps4jsf

I'm using [gmaps4jsf](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/) and I see that you can set markers based on lat and long, but how can you set markers based on an address? All the examples on the net are for version < 3.0 and they show the `<m:marker>` tag with an attribute of address, but the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/wiki/markerComponent) does not have that attribute and when i try setting it anyways, it doesn't work unless i use lat/long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMaps4JSF's marker has an address attribute since its early days, here are online examples:
http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/addressableMarkers.xhtml 
http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/addressableMarkers.xhtml.source

The documentation was just missing this attribute.

Comment: Ahh i see. I must have been hitting the limit before. Seems like after 10 markers it doesn't put anymore on there.

Comment: yeah the 10 markers limits are some pain, i'm trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762839/javascript-google-maps-displays-only-10-markers-out-of-100-is-there-a-limit